# How do I improve virtualbox ubuntu performance

Tags: virtualbox, performance

Currently running ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 on virtualbox with an i7 3770k @ 4.2GHz and a GTX 770 with 3d acceleration enabled. I also have two cores and 4gb of ram assigned. I am using a 30GB fixed disk on my HDD. I have also installed the guest additions CD.

My performance is a little slow especially when I scroll through the app drawer. Is it possible to improve my performance further or is it always going to run a little slow through virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualbox being what it is (running one operating system on top of another), you will always notice a hair of a thing of speed difference between your host operating system and your virtual machine.

You could try assigning more ram or more cores temporarily just to see whether it improves performance at all.  Also make sure your CPU execution cap is at 100%.